# Redirect to URL after jQuery function is executed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery function so that when I click on a link in my nav bar all the content on the pages 'falls off' the page using the Fly Off Page plugin. I would like to redirect to this URL after my function is executed, I have tried using a timeout function, but this does not work for me.

```
 $('a').click(function(event) { 
        $('*').flyOffPage( {
            duration: 1000, //falling speed in milliseconds
            direction: 'btn',
        }, {
            complete: setTimeout(function() {
                        $(this).load('href');
            }, 100000)
        });
    });
```

Comment: Do you want to keep the user on the same page and just load the conent there through Ajax or wanting to load a whole new page?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to redirect then the function is `window.location.href = 'your URL'`

Answer (score 0):

The document says there is no complete callback method defined in this plugin.

Try this code:

```
$('a').click(function(event) { 
    $('*').flyOffPage( {
        duration: 1000, //falling speed in milliseconds
        direction: 'btn'
    });

    var a = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        a.load('http://google.com');
    }, 1000);
    return false;
});
```